# Soap Message Deserialization

Tags: c#, soap, deserialization

I have soap message like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <ShipNo_Check xmlns="http://bimgewebservices.gmb.gov.tr">          
      <shipNo>13343100VB0000000014</shipNo>
      <harborNo>1234567</harborNo>
    </ShipNo_Check>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

In my asp.net mvc application, I need to serialize this xml. I am using this method:

```
public object SoapTo(string soapString) {
    IFormatter formatter;
    MemoryStream memStream = null;
    Object objectFromSoap = null;
    try {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[soapString.Length];

        Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(soapString, 0,
                     soapString.Length, bytes, 0);
        memStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        formatter = new SoapFormatter();
        objectFromSoap = formatter.Deserialize(memStream);
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        throw exception;
    }
    finally {
        if (memStream != null) memStream.Close();
    }
    return objectFromSoap;
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Parse Error, no assembly associated with Xml key _P1 ShipNo_Check
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The XML you have is invalid: the open tag `<harborNo>` is closed by `</tasitNo>`.

Comment: I did mistake while doing copy-paste.I have edited my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One alternative is to use WCF to deserialize it - for which you'll need to define a class which maps to the body of your message. The code below shows one way how this can be implemented.

```
public class StackOverflow_24559375
{
    const string XML = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
        <s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
          <s:Body>
            <ShipNo_Check xmlns=""http://bimgewebservices.gmb.gov.tr"">          
              <shipNo>13343100VB0000000014</shipNo>
              <harborNo>1234567</harborNo>
            </ShipNo_Check>
          </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>";

    [DataContract(Name = "ShipNo_Check", Namespace = "http://bimgewebservices.gmb.gov.tr")]
    public class ShipNo_Check
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "shipNo", Order = 1)]
        public string ShipNo { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "harborNo", Order = 2)]
        public string HarborNo { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(XML)))
        {
            Message m = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
            var body = m.GetBody<ShipNo_Check>();
            Console.WriteLine(body.ShipNo + " - " + body.HarborNo);
        }
    }
}
```